# do we need to add bank details in stripe to receive payments

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, stripe-payments, bank

I am making a site(React js and firebase) where I want to recive payments with stripe. I want to know that do we need to add bank details to recive payments

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll need to set up a Stripe account. Start here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/register

Comment: I have a stripe account but should I add bank details to it

Comment: According to Stripe, "Set up your bank account to receive payouts."

https://stripe.com/docs/payouts

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer if it helped.